# Express: router.route does not send request but keeps going

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code in my `Express` app:

```
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
 // connect to our database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:pwd@<url>/db-name');

var Bear = require('./app/models/bear');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;        // set our port

var router = express.Router();   

//middleware to use for all requests
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // do logging
    console.log('Something is happening.');
    next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
});

router.route('/bears')

  .get(function(req, res) {
    Bear.find(function(err, bears) {
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        console.log('I am in GET');
        res.json(bears);
    });
  })
  .post(function(req, res) {
    var bear = new Bear();
    bear.name = req.body.name;
    console.log('body param:'+ bear.name);
    bear.save(function(err) {
        if(err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Bear created!'});
    });
  });

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });
});

app.use('/api', router);


app.listen(port);
```

Here is my `Model` code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BearSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear', BearSchema);
```

When I either use POSTMAN or browser the request keeps going and does not stop or return anything. I think the callback should be ended but dont know how.

I'm hitting `http://localhost:8080/api/bears` and it keeps refreshing and the request never ends.

Output from server when I hit /api/bears & request does not end:

```
Something is happening.
```

Output from server when I hit /api

```
Something is happening.
```

and on browser I see,

```
Cannot GET /api
```

Comment: What requests do you send? Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: @AlexanderMac http://localhost:8080/api/bears and no console errors and it does not print `I am in GET`

Comment: Do you use additional middleware `app.use('/api', you_router)`?

Comment: @AlexanderMac yes I do

Comment: Do you see `Something is happening.` message? And add to the question app.js, where you have defined `app.use('/api', you_router)` middleware

Comment: Yes I see that message 'something is happening and I have app.use at the bottom

Comment: Is `/api` your base path ? If not then try `localhost:8080/bears`.

Comment: @AlexanderMac I updated my code

Comment: The order of your routes declaration is invalid, one of possible solutions to fix that is remove `app.use('/api', ...` and add `/api` to `/bears`: `router.get('/api/bears')`

Comment: @AlexanderMac what should be the order?

Comment: Currently your routes looks so: `GET /bears`, `POST /bears`, ' GET /', `GET /api/bears`, `POST /api/bears`. The express executes the first matched route, when you request `GET /api/bears`, express executes action for route `/`.

Comment: Even if I removed `/api` completely it does not work

Comment: What issue you are facing? Please update the question with details. I am  able to hit the urls with your code if I remove the bear models. are you hitting the correct port? you should get the output from the middleware atleast in the server console.

Comment: @avck I have updated my answer

Comment: you are not getting any output in the log from the middleware? In that case the request is not reaching the server. are you able to hit localhost:8080/api and get response?

Comment: @avck I added more info

Comment: you have not connected to the mongodb instace it seems. use `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');`

Comment: @avck I have that but due to security reasons I did post it

Comment: I am clueless now, try putting `router.route('/'){. ...}` before `router.route('/bear').{ ...}` and also put logs at various points to trace till where it is reaching.  On my setup i can get the horray message but I do not have bear model or mongoose, so its definitely trouble with db connection/interaction. One more thing to try is does mongoose contain find(callback) method or it is find({},callback)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the `mongooose` version in my package.json. I changed to latest version `4.1.11` and did a `npm install`. This is a bug: https://github.com/meanjs/mean/issues/1010

I added the following code to make sure I was getting no error and a success:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://db-name:pwd@mongourl:port/db', function(err) {
   if(err) {
     console.log(err);
   } else {
     console.log('success');
   }
 });
```

I received this:

```
{ [MongoError: auth failed] name: 'MongoError', ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth failed', code: 18 }
```

I then used `RoboMongo` to connect and it was all fine so I started looking at the bugs. `RoboMongo` used `SCRAM-SHA-1` as auth mechanism. I started looking to specify auth as a option in my URL where I came across the above bug report.